# How to implement pipes for multiple processes?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, pipe

I am creating multiple processes and *I need to create two unnamed pipes for each process.*

For each child, one pipe will be used to get int value from parent; one for sending to int arrays to parent. Parent will do some things **while** getting new data from childs.

The base code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> // for reaching unix operations


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t main = getpid();

    int N = 30;
    int i;
    pid_t* children = (pid_t*) malloc(sizeof(pid_t) * N);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        pid_t child = fork();
        if ( child == 0){
            pid_t me = getpid();
            printf("I'm a child and my pid is: %d\n", me);
             sleep(1);
            // exit(4);
            return me * 2;
        } else if ( child < 0){
            // printf("Could not create child\n");
        } else {
            children[i] = child;
            // printf("I have created a child and its pid %d\n", child);
        }
    }

    // The child never reaches here
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int status;
        waitpid(children[i], &status, 0);
        printf("Process %d exited with return code %d\n", children[i], WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried many things with no success and I'm lost. Can you help me to continue?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how to set up one pipe for each child process so that each child writes to the parent:

Since you need two file descriptors for each child, declare:

```
int fd[2 * N];
```

Initialize them appropriately:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pipe(&fd[2*i]);
}
```

---

Inside the `i`-th child process, use:

```
write(fd[2*i + 1], write_buffer, SIZE)
```

to write to the parent, and in the parent use:

```
 read(fd[2*i], read_buffer, SIZE)
```

to read from the `i`-th child.

---

To close the pipes:

Inside the `i`-th child, you can use

```
close(fd[2*i])
```

right away, seeing as you're only writing. After you're done writing call

```
close(fd[2*i + 1])
```

to close the write end of the pipe.

The situation is parallel in the parent: when reading from the `i`-th child you can

```
close(fd[2*i + 1])
```

right away, since you're not writing, and after you're done reading call

```
close(fd[2*i])
```

to close the read end of the pipe.

---

Since you need *two* pipes per child process, create two arrays - one containing pipes for the children writing to the parent, and one containing pipes for the parent writing to the children.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying it now. My prof wrote that "You can create  two pipes per child (one for each direction of communication between parent and child)". So this is pointless?

Comment: @user4220128 Pipes are used for communicating in just one direction. If you need the child to both read from *and* write to the parent, then you'll need two pipes.

Comment: Actually, reads and writes should be done at parent AND children. Parent sends ints to children, also read int arrays from children. Children reads ints from parent and writes int arrays to parent. May I put everything into fd in this case?

Comment: @user4220128 I've edited my answer to include this information.

Comment: it works!! Can I read multiple integers inside child from parent, using these codes? I tried `while (read(fd2[2*i], &read_buffer, sizeof(int)) > 0){
    printf("Parent sent %d to Child %d\n", read_buffer, i);
   }` but it only reads one integer.

Comment: Note that parent send one int at a time to a process. But there can be many ints to send.

Comment: @user4220128 `read` will return 0 if there's no more data in the pipe, which seems to be the case here. You can use semaphores and set it up so that each time the parent writes, the child is woken and reads the data. You can also have the child read indefinitely, although that would be inefficient.

Comment: Thanks again btw. E.g. I wrote 10 integers but i can only read 1 of them. I'm trying to read all. I think I am able to write multiple integers but reading them is the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Child outputs the last integer from the set of integers written. It is not 0.