# About Inter-process communication in C, Using pipe()

Tags: linux, posix

I'm trying to write sort function.

This function may fork many children to help itself to sort the given input.

When my function has only one child it is easy to use `pipe()`. I just create

```
int fd[2];
```

then everything is fine but I don't know what to do when there are many children. Should I create `fd[Children*2]` pipes or `fd[2]` is enough?

And how can i use these pipes to communicate with the child that I want (since there are many children)?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636260/how-to-implement-pipes-for-multiple-processes/28636426#28636426).

Comment: you should provide a little example, the code explain better the problems

Comment: It depends.  Will only your first program fork children or will children fork further children too?

Comment: It is not standard C99 (or C11), it is POSIX or Linux, and should be tagged as such.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Basile

Answer (score 0):

My main process will fork children, this is just one part of the code, I'm forking children and getting their pids into pid array

```
pid_t main = getpid();

int N = 30;
pid_t* children = (pid_t*) malloc(sizeof(pid_t) * N);
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    pid_t child = fork();
    if ( child == 0){
        pid_t me = getpid();
        printf("I'm a child and my pid is: %d\n", me);
        sleep(1);
        // exit(4);
        return me * 2;
    } else if ( child < 0){
        // printf("Could not create child\n");
    } else {
        children[i] = child;
        // printf("I have created a child and its pid %d\n", child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If only the main process needs to create and communicate with children, and the children don't need to communicate with each other, create a separate pipe for each child in the main process before forking the child.  The call to [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) could be placed in your loop, before calling [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html).  You could use a 2-dimensional array like `fd[NUM_CHILDREN][2]` to keep track of the file descriptors.  If the data will be arriving asynchronously, [`poll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) or [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) can be used to find out when something is available to be read.