# Using pipes with multiple children and only one parent

Tags: c, pipe, fork

So, i'm doing a project which requires me to use fork() to create 1 parent process and 10 child processes, which each one will communicate with the parent process using pipes, one pipe which the parent writes to the child, and one where the child writes to the parent, and lastly each child process needs it own pipe. So in total 20 pipes, if i've understood the assignment correctly.
But i've having an issue where whatever i sent through the pipes, when its read its always 2496.
I've tried doing a double array pipe if thats even a thing (fd[10][2]), it didnt work
I've tried doing a 2 big pipes using this as a guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636260/how-to-implement-pipes-for-multiple-processes
Still didnt work.
Anyone got a clue whats the issue with the pipes and how to fix them?
The code i've written is below:

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct Flights{
    int flight_id;
    char from_city[50];
    char to_city[50];
    int available_seats;
    int price;
    int sinolo;
    int apotixia;
    int epitixia;
}flight[10];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int p1[20];
    int p2[20];
    int new_process;
    int price1=0;
    int price2=0;
    int price3=0;
    pid_t ppid;
    pid_t cpid;
    int tickets;
    int pricetot;
    int id1;
    int id2;
    int id3;
    int request1=0;
    int request2=0;
    int request3=0;
    int epitixia=0;
    int sinolo=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    strcpy(flight[0].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[0].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[0].flight_id = 9;
    flight[0].price = 200;
    flight[0].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[0].sinolo=0;
    flight[0].apotixia=0;
    flight[0].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[1].from_city, "Chania");
    strcpy(flight[1].to_city, "Athens");
    flight[1].flight_id = 8;
    flight[1].price = 150;
    flight[1].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[1].sinolo=0;
    flight[1].apotixia=0;
    flight[1].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[2].from_city, "Thessaloniki");
    strcpy(flight[2].to_city, "Athens");
    flight[2].flight_id = 7;
    flight[2].price = 300;
    flight[2].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[2].sinolo=0;
    flight[2].apotixia=0;
    flight[2].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[3].from_city, "Thessaloniki");
    strcpy(flight[3].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[3].flight_id = 6;
    flight[3].price = 200;
    flight[3].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[3].sinolo=0;
    flight[3].apotixia=0;
    flight[3].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[4].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[4].to_city, "Chania");
    flight[4].flight_id = 5;
    flight[4].price = 400;
    flight[4].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[4].sinolo=0;
    flight[4].apotixia=0;
    flight[4].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[5].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[5].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[5].flight_id = 4;
    flight[5].price = 250;
    flight[5].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[5].sinolo=0;
    flight[5].apotixia=0;
    flight[5].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[6].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[6].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[6].flight_id = 3;
    flight[6].price = 250;
    flight[6].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[6].sinolo=0;
    flight[6].apotixia=0;
    flight[6].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[7].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[7].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[7].flight_id = 2;
    flight[7].price = 250;
    flight[7].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[7].sinolo=0;
    flight[7].apotixia=0;
    flight[7].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[8].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[8].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[8].flight_id = 1;
    flight[8].price = 250;
    flight[8].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[8].sinolo=0;
    flight[8].apotixia=0;
    flight[8].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[9].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[9].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[9].flight_id = 10;
    flight[9].price = 250;
    flight[9].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[9].sinolo=0;
    flight[9].apotixia=0;
    flight[9].epitixia=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pipe(&p1[2*i]);
    pipe(&p2[2*i]);
    }
    for(int l=0;l<10;l++){
        //if(pipe(p1[l]) == -1) {return 1;}
        //if(pipe(p2[l]) == -1) {return 2;}
        new_process=fork();
        if(new_process== -1) {return 3;}
        else if(new_process == 0){
            srand(time(NULL) ^ (getpid()));
            close(p1[2*l]);
            close(p2[2*l + 1]);
            tickets=rand()%3+1;
            //tickets=3;
            printf("tickets %d\n",tickets);
            id1=(rand()%10);
            id1++;
            printf("Id1 pre pipe %d\n",id1);
            if(write(p1[2*l], &tickets, sizeof(tickets)) == -1) {return 4;}
            if(write(p1[2*l], &id1, sizeof(id1)) == -1) {return 5;}
            if (tickets==2){
             id2=(rand()%10);
             id2++;
             if(write(p1[2*l+1], &id2, sizeof(id2)) == -1) {return 6;}
            }
            else if (tickets==3){
             id2=(rand()%10);
             id2++;
             printf("Id2 pre pipe %d\n",id2);
             if(write(p1[2*l+1], &id2, sizeof(id2)) == -1) {return 6;}
             id3=(rand()%10);
             id3++;
             printf("Id3 pre pipe %d\n",id3);
             if(write(p1[2*l+1], &id3, sizeof(id3)) == -1) {return 7;}
            }
            close(p1[2*l + 1]);
            pause();
            if(read(p2[2*l], &request1, sizeof(request1)) == -1) {return 8;}
            if (request1==1){
                printf("The request for flight %d, was successfull\n",id1);
            }
            else if(request1==2){
                printf("The request for flight %d, was unsuccessfull,not enough available seats\n",id1);
            }
            if (tickets==2 || tickets==3){
                if(read(p2[2*l], &request2, sizeof(request2)) == -1) {return 9;}
                if (request2==1){
                    printf("The request for flight %d, was successfull\n",id2);
                }
                else if(request2==2){
                    printf("The request for flight %d, was unsuccessfull,not enough available seats\n",id2);
                }
                if (tickets==3){
                    if(read(p2[2*l], &request3, sizeof(request3)) == -1) {return 10;}
                    if (request3==1){
                     printf("The request for flight %d, was successfull\n",id3);
                    }
                    else if(request3==2){
                        printf("The request for flight %d, was unsuccessfull,not enough available seats\n",id3);
                    }
                }
            }
            close(p2[2*l]);
            l=11;
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            close(p1[2*l + 1]);
            close(p2[2*l]);
            if(read(p1[2*l], &tickets, sizeof(tickets)) == -1) {return 11;}
            if(read(p1[2*l], &id1, sizeof(id1)) == -1) {return 12;}
            printf("Id:%d Tickets:%d\n",id1,tickets);
            for (int t=0;t<tickets;t++){
                for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
                    if (t==0){
                    if(id1 == flight[x].flight_id)
                    {
                        if(flight[x].available_seats-1>=0){
                            x=10;
                            flight[x].available_seats=flight[x].available_seats-1;
                            flight[x].epitixia++;
                            flight[x].sinolo++;
                            sinolo++;
                            epitixia++;
                            price1=flight[x].price;
                            pricetot=pricetot+price1;
                                request1=1;
                                request2=0;
                                request3=0;
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &request1, sizeof(request1)) == -1) {return 13;}
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &price1, sizeof(price1)) == -1) {return 14;}
                        }
                        else{
                            x=10;
                            request1=2;
                            request2=0;
                            request3=0;
                            if(write(p2[2*l+1], &request1, sizeof(request1)) == -1) {return 13;}
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    else if (t==1){
                        if(read(p1[2*l], &id2, sizeof(id2)) == -1) {return 19;}
                        printf("Id2 ap:%d\n",id2);
                        if(id2 == flight[x].flight_id){
                            if(flight[x].available_seats-1>=0){
                                x=10;
                                flight[x].available_seats=flight[x].available_seats-1;
                                flight[x].epitixia++;
                                flight[x].sinolo++;
                                sinolo++;
                                epitixia++;
                                price2=flight[x].price;
                                pricetot=pricetot+price2;
                                request2=1;
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &request2, sizeof(request2)) == -1) {return 15;}
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &price2, sizeof(price2)) == -1) {return 16;}
                            }
                            else{
                                x=10;
                                request2=2;
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &request2, sizeof(request2)) == -1) {return 15;}
                                flight[x].apotixia++;
                                flight[x].sinolo++;
                                sinolo++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (t==2){
                        if(read(p1[2*l], &id3, sizeof(id3)) == -1) {return 12;}
                        printf("Id3 ap:%d\n",id3);
                        if(id3 == flight[x].flight_id){
                            if(flight[x].available_seats-1>=0){
                                x=10;
                                flight[x].available_seats=flight[x].available_seats-1;
                                flight[x].epitixia++;
                                flight[x].sinolo++;
                                sinolo++;
                                epitixia++;
                                price3=flight[x].price;
                                pricetot=pricetot+price3;
                                request3=1;
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &request3, sizeof(request3)) == -1) {return 17;}
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &price3, sizeof(price3)) == -1) {return 18;}
                            }
                            else{
                                x=10;
                                request3=2;
                                if(write(p2[2*l+1], &request3, sizeof(request3)) == -1) {return 15;}
                                flight[x].apotixia++;
                                flight[x].sinolo++;
                                sinolo++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        close(p1[2*l]);
        close(p2[2*l + 1]);
        kill(cpid, SIGCONT);
        sleep(0.5);
        wait(NULL);
    }
        for(int h=0;h<10;h++){
        printf("From: %s, To: %s\nSinolo:%d, Epitixia: %d, Apotixia: %d\n\n",flight[h].from_city,flight[h].to_city,flight[h].sinolo,flight[h].epitixia,flight[h].apotixia);
        }
        printf("Profit: %d, Sinolo: %d, Epitixia: %d\n",pricetot,sinolo,epitixia);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: You really need to have a bit of modularity in your program...

Comment: You should use 2-dimensional arrays: `int pipe_to_child[10][2]; int pipe_from_child[10][2];`

Comment: One way to resolve problems like this is to work on a simpler version of it. In this case, can you successfully create the pipes for a single child?